# Evaluating expressions consisting of elementwise matrix operations in Thrust

Tags: cuda, thrust

I would like to use Thrust to evaluate expressions consisting of elementwise matrix operations. To make it clear, let us consider an expression like:

`D=A*B+3*sin(C)`

where `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are matrices, of course of the same size.

The [Thrust Quick Start Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html) provides the `saxpy` example for which `y` is used both as input and as output, while in my case the output argument is different from the input ones which, by the way, are more than two. At [Element-by-element vector multiplication with CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899237/element-by-element-vector-multiplication-with-cuda), the case of output different than the input, but of only two inputs, is considered.

Could anyone provide some suggestions (and possibly the rationale behind) on how using Thrust to implement the expression above (output matrix different from the inputs and more than two inputs)? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at [Newton](https://github.com/jaredhoberock/newton)? That is a working prototype of expression templates using thrust.

Comment: @talonmies No. Actually, I have my own expression templates library and wanted to benchmark the performance against thrust... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to implement that computation with [Newton](https://github.com/jaredhoberock/newton), which is the library mentioned in talonmies' comment:

```
#include <newton/newton.hpp>

int main()
{
  float a[4] = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
  float b[4] = {2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0};
  float c[4] = {3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0};
  float d[4] = {4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0};

  newton::numeric_vector<float> A = a;
  newton::numeric_vector<float> B = b;
  newton::numeric_vector<float> C = c;
  newton::numeric_vector<float> D = d;

  D = A * B + 3.f * sin(C);

  return 0;
}
```

The library is built using `thrust::zip_iterator` and `thrust::transform_iterator` to implement expressions with an arbitrary number of inputs. You can refer to the implementation for the details.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will surely take a look at your implementation of expression templates using thrust. As I have mentioned to talonmies, I have my own implementation of expression templates in CUDA and I would like to figure out how faster it is as compared to a "standard" implementation involving temporaries. Therefore, I was planning to use matrix operations with "pure" thrust. My concern is that if I use Newton, as you suggest, then I would not see the effect of the creation of temporaries. What do you think about?

Comment: There are no temporaries created in the `D = A * B + 3.f * sin(C)` expression. The assignment should result in a single kernel launch.

Comment: Yes, of course. But in my test now I _do want_ the creation of temporaries to understand how much do I gain by expression templates...

Comment: It sounds like you're asking how to implement that expression as inefficiently as possible :) I suppose you could create functions such as `operator+` which take `device_vector<float>` parameters and return `device_vector<float>` as a value. The implementation of such functions would just use `thrust::transform`.

Comment: In some sense, yes :-) I verified that evaluating expressions by my metaprogramming implementation takes the same time as by hand-written kernels, so I'm happy. I wanted then to compare such performance with that of an already available library and I thought about thrust. But thrust means "pure" thrust, without the help of Newton :-) Of course, it would be interesting to compare the performance of my implementation with that of your own library and, if my mine will tend to yours, I will be happy :-) From what you mentioned, making the test with thrust will require some effort.

Comment: For the moment knowing that thrust is not ready to evaluate expressions and requires some operator overloads is enough for me since now I understand that the effort to overload operators is justified, as you and talonmies observed, only if metaprogramming is simultaneously used. Again, Thanks.