# How to do element wise exponential for a matrix in Cuda programming

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, gpu, cublas

How to do element wise exponential for a matrix in Cuda programming?

for example:

A = [1 3 4; 6 5 2];

I want to compute:

B = [exp(1),exp(3),exp(4); exp(6);exp(5);(2)]

Is there a way of doing it efficiently and doing it in place (i.e, B replaces A)? 
It seems cublas does not provide element wise operation on matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if libraries exist that do element wise operations on matrices, but you could easily set up a CUDA kernel to do this job. You could for instance give one element of the `A` matrix to each thread, and they could perform the exponential and write the answer in `B`. You then call your CUDA kernel as usual. Take a look [at this](http://www.arc.vt.edu/resources/software/cuda/docs/MatMul.cu) to get an idea of how to implement your kernel and how to call it (but instead of multiplying two vectors like they do in `gpuMM` you would do an exponential).

**EDIT**: It looks like you can do element wise operations using [Thrust](http://thrust.github.io/) and the set of macros [Newton](https://github.com/jaredhoberock/newton), as is shown in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487322/evaluating-expressions-consisting-of-elementwise-matrix-operations-in-thrust).