# how to compile cuda newton template meta-programming sample program

Tags: cuda, template-meta-programming

How do I compile the sample cuda newton metaprogramming program in

[Evaluating expressions consisting of elementwise matrix operations in Thrust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487322/evaluating-expressions-consisting-of-elementwise-matrix-operations-in-thrust?rq=1)

For reference, newton is here: https://github.com/jaredhoberock/newton

Here is the start of my output:

```
nvcc -I. -I/local/cuda/include test_newton.cu  
nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use -Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).
./newton/detail/range/range_traits.hpp(171): error: expected a ">"

./newton/detail/range/range_traits.hpp(177): warning: parsing restarts here after previous syntax error

./newton/detail/range/range_traits.hpp(171): error: mismatched delimiters in default argument expression

./newton/detail/range/range_traits.hpp(177): error: expected a "," or ">"

./newton/detail/range/range_traits.hpp(177): error: expected a "," or ">"

./newton/detail/range/range_traits.hpp(177): error: expected a declaration

./newton/detail/arithmetic.hpp(35): error: namespace "newton::detail" has no member "lazy_enable_if_at_least_one_is_range"

./newton/detail/arithmetic.hpp(36): error: namespace "newton::detail" has no member "lazy_enable_if_at_least_one_is_range"

./newton/detail/arithmetic.hpp(37): error: namespace "newton::detail" has no member "lazy_enable_if_at_least_one_is_range"
```

This is my nvcc:

```
nvcc -V                                        
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2016 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jan_10_13:22:03_CST_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 8.0, V8.0.61
```

Finally, since newton has had no changes in two years, is it something that I should even be trying to use?  I do like what it's trying to do.

Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to compile by separating >> into > > in the template. Apparently some versions of C++ allow >>  but others do not.

That raised other questions that I'll post separately.